# Podman container on server only reachable if using network option host

Tags: networking, server, podman

I want to run two containers on the same server via podman.

1. A frontend server that should be reachable from the internet via `<server_ip>:4200`
2. A backend server that should be reachable from by the webserver via `localhost:8000`

The following works on my local pc but not on the server:

1. Create a pod that will contain the two containers, so the frontend can reach the backend using `localhost` and publish the ports 4200 and 8000:

`podman pod create -p 4200:4200 -p 8000:8000 --name=mypod`

2. Run both containers inside the pod:

`podman run --pod=mypod <frontend_image_id>`

`podman run --pod=mypod <backend_image_id>`

When doing the same on the server I the containers are not reachable from outside the server via `<server_ip>:4200` or `<server_ip>:8000`. From inside the server, e.g. via `curl localhost:4200` the containers are reachable.

What also works is deploying containers on the server using the network option `host` as follows.

`podman run --network host <image_id>`

In that case, the containers are reachable via `<server_ip>:4200` or `<server_ip>:8000` from the outside but don't reach each other via `localhost`.

I must be missing something here, please help or explain this behavior.

Comment: I think you would normally port-forward from your public network-interface to the localhost port or have a proxy running to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Saw this in another thread sometime ago , but have you checked your firewall config ?

If your running a redhat dist (fedora, centos, rhel) , try add the ports to your firewall. Run this as root.

```
firewall-cmd --add-port=4200/tcp --permanent 
firewall-cmd --add-port=8000/tcp --permanent 
firewall-cmd --reload
```

I had the same issue when running podman as non root user and that worked for me.